# What's the reason for the behaviour of these expressions?

Tags: java, groovy

```
println (0>4​)​<5​ // prints true
println (0<4​)​<5​ // prints true
println (0>4)​>5​ // prints false
println (0<4)>5 // prints true
```

***When I try to extract the class of this expression,​ it results in java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean. Why does it try casting the expression back from Integer to Boolean?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `(0<4)<5` is invalid syntax in both Groovy and Java. `(0<4)` is a `boolean` (or `Boolean` when boxed) and cannot be compared with an `int` (or `Integer` when boxed). That's why you get that error message.

`println (0<4)<5` is actually parsed as `println(0<4) < 5`, so it compares the return value of `println(0<4)` which is `println(true)`, with the value `5`.

In Groovy, `println` returns `null`. This can be compared with any `Object`, for some peculiar reason. `null` compares equal to `null` and less than any real object, including the `Integer` object `5`.

Comment: If what you say is correct, then EVERY println should return null, and all 4 statements should print `true`. But the question says that `println (0>4)​>5​ // prints false`.

Comment: @manassehkatz yes, that is correct, expected behaviour. `println (0>4)​>5` means `null > 5` which is false, since null is less than anything.

Comment: You're right - I missed that one. So the end result is either (the way most languages work) the () expression evaluates to 0 or 1 and is always < 5, or the evaluation is irrelevant and println == null which is always < 5. So it is either a "normal" language and works like my answer or it is a strange (IMHO) language and works like your answer!

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou
I noticed that I missed a case, println (0<4)>5. In this case, it returns true, but as per your explanation, it should have returned false.

Comment: @dev-eloper if you run that expression in Groovy Console (the GUI app) it does two things. On the first line, it prints "true". Then on the second line, it prints "Result: false". The first line is the output from `println`. The expression `0<4` is true, hence println prints "true". Then the Groovy Console evaluates the *whole* expression `println (0<4)>5` which is false, and prints the result: "Result: false". You can also get the same result (minus println's output) by typing just "null > 5" into the Groovy Console.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Thanks, mate.

Answer (score 0):

In many languages, a boolean expression will automatically cast to an integer when used in a numeric expression, with True==>1 and False ==>0. So `0>4` = False = 0, `0<4` = True = 1. That turns the statements into:

```
println 0​<5
println 1​<5​
println 0​>5​
println 0<5​
```

which results in True, True, False, True as you found.

Comment: Thanks. 
Just curious, when I try to extract the class of this expression, why does it try casting? Shouldn't it simply say Integer rather than throwing 'java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean exception'?

Comment: I actually don't know the answer to that part as it is Java specific. But the basic println expressions are the same as you would find in almost any language with fairly flexible types.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're way off the mark. Groovy works in peculiar ways.